# How to replace some characters of input file, before it getting lexed in flex?

Tags: flex-lexer

How to replace all occurrences of some character or char-sequence with some other character or char-sequence, before flex lexes it. For example I want `B\65R` to match `identifier` rule as it is equivalent to `BAR` in my grammar. So, essentially I want to turn a sequence of `\dd` into its equivalent ascii character and then lex it. (\65 -> A, \66 -> B, …).

I know, I can first search the entire file for a sequence of `\dd` and replace it with equivalent character and then feed it to flex. But I wonder if there exists a better way. Something like writing a rule that matches `\dd` and then replacing it with corresponding alternative in the input stream, so that, I don't have to parse entire file twice.

Answer (score 0):

Several options...

Next, flex is going to read from a filter that
substitutes "\dd" by "chr(dd)" (untested).

You could run something along the lines of

```
YYIN = popen("perl -pe 's/\\(\d\d)/chr($1)/e' ", "r");
yylex()....
```

Comment: This requires completely scanning the file twice.. (Once during replacing and once for actual lexing). So, is it possible to do text replacement in lexer itself?