# Handling different line ending conventions with Flex

Tags: flex-lexer

I need to handle all common line ending conventions with Flex, i.e. LF, CRLF, or potentially other combinations of CR and LF.  Matching and end-of-line can be done with `[\n\r]+` (since ignoring repeated newlines is fine in this application).

But what about matching a beginning of line with `^`? I assume that for the purposes of matching `^`, Flex assumes `\n` to be the newline, which is system-dependent. Is this correct?

What is the best way to match text that may only appear at the beginning of the line, akin to `^something`, when we need to handle different newline conventions? I attempted to solve this by activating a "beginning of line" start condition whenever matching a newline. But I don't have a robust way to switch out of this start condition in good time.

Comment: I did find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43174340/695132), which offers a solution, but the comments under it suggest that it might have a severe performance impact.

Comment: `\n`always *is* the new line. The only system dependency is whether or not a `\r` precedes it. You’re unlikely to encounter a system with a different convention. They exist, but they’re rare.

Comment: @user207421 Yeah, as far as I could find last systems that was using `\r` changed that around the year 2001. As long as you're working with ASCII, `\r?\n` should work reliably.

Comment: Good point, if I restrict support to `\r?\n` then there's no issue with `^`, and anything else is probably not worth supporting.

Comment: I think the `\r?\n` is best, but you'll still need to be careful about `.` matching `\r` in other rules due to greediness. Also, `$` won't work as intended when `\r` is next in the buffer. One other thing is that you can force a "beginning of line" status in the lexer context with the `yy_set_bol()` macro. So maybe `[\r\n]+ { yy_set_bol(1); }` would allow `^` to work normally?

Comment: @Gene I think the `yy_set_bol` comment should be an answer (that I will accept).

Comment: No worries. I don't want to post an answer that I have no time to test. I'm glad if it works for you.